# Add additional amount to stripe checkout

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I have working on E-commerce website using python/Django. I have integrated stripe payments where carts items are dynamically passed as line items . I added as delivery fee if the cart value is less than Rs.500. Current using the stripe session Api for checkout process. I want to add the delivery fee as extra amount to the checkout line items price. **Thanks in advance**

```
@csrf_exempt
def createCheckoutSession(request):


if request.method=='GET':
    domain_url='http://localhost:8000/'
    stripe.api_key= settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)


    try:
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(profile.stripe_id)
        print (customer)
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        checkoutSession = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url =domain_url+'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url =domain_url+'cancelled/',
        payment_method_types = ['card'],
        mode='payment',
        line_items= get_line_items(request)[0],
        customer= profile.stripe_id,


        )



        return JsonResponse({'sessionId':checkoutSession['id']})


    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"error":str(e)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this, but one way would be to create a delivery Price via the dashboard or API. Then if the sum of the line items price `unit_amounts` is less than 500 add the shipping Price to the line items and pass the items array to the session create call:

```
# The shipping price ID
shipping_price = "price_xxx"

# Base price
price = stripe.Price.retrieve(
  "price_yyy",
)

# If there are more than one item you can iterate over items and sum the unit_amounts
items = [
  {
    "price": price.id,
    "quantity": 1,
  },
]

# For simplicity I assume there is only one price being charged, for summing, iterate over the items
if(price.unit_amount < 500):
  items.append({
    "price": shipping_price,
    "quantity": 1,
  })

stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://example.com/success",
  cancel_url="https://example.com/cancel",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  line_items=items,
  mode="payment",
)
```

Comment: Thanks @v3nkman  for the idea. if cart value is more than 500 . I added delivery fee as line item with quantity 1